# Wrapping a tornado.gen.engine-wrapped function with another function

Tags: python, asynchronous, generator, tornado

Say, I have a function, that is wrapped with gen.engine to "straighten out" the callback chain, that is, so that the code appears to be synchronous / linear / whatever.

The function, then looks like this

```
@gen.engine
def func():
     ...
     yield gen.Task(...)
     ...
     yield gen.Task(...)
```

and so on. I understand, that I definitely can use try / except around `yield`s to catch exceptions occuring in the function, that is wrapped by `gen.Task`. What if I need to wrap the function `func` itself in another function to (this is the actual use case) catch all "uncaught" exceptions in `func` without introducing an "ugly" (right..) try / except, that will span the entire `func`?

I've come up with this:

```
@gen.engine
def func(..., callback):
     ...
     callback()

@gen.engine
def outer():
    try:
        yield gen.Task(func)
    except Exception as e:
        # Log the exception
    # Stop ioloop (or something)
```

This adds a bit of generality to `func`, but introduces an extra argument and some artificial logic in `func`.

Is there any other way of doing this? Do note, that the "emergency exceptions catching" is more or less an artificial use case for the purpose of this question (this can probably done in some other way), what I am looking is the correct way of calling those tornado.gen.engine-wrapped functions from another functions.

Edit: silly me, I should've mentioned that I am restricted to tornado 2.x!

Answer (score 6):

`@gen.coroutine` is a new feature of Tornado 3. From http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/releases/v3.0.0.html:

> New decorator @gen.coroutine is available as an alternative to
>   @gen.engine. It automatically returns a Future, and within the
>   function instead of calling a callback you return a value with raise
>   gen.Return(value) (or simply return value in Python 3.3).

From documentation(http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#tornado.gen.coroutine):

> Functions with this decorator return a Future. Additionally, they may
>   be called with a callback keyword argument, which will be invoked with
>   the future’s result when it resolves. If the coroutine fails, the callback will not be run and an exception will be raised into the surrounding StackContext. The callback argument is not visible inside the decorated function; it is handled by the decorator itself.

Therefore there is no reason to worry about callbacks and there is no need to wrap functions into `tornado.gen.Task()`. Chaining is easy now:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import logging

import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web
import tornado.gen

from tornado.options import define, options
define("port", default=8000, help="run on the given port", type=int)

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def outer(self):
        logging.info('outer starts')
        yield self.inner()
        yield self.inner()  
        logging.info('outer ends')  
        raise tornado.gen.Return('hello')

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def inner(self):
        logging.info('inner runs')

    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        res = yield self.outer()
        self.write(res)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    app = tornado.web.Application(handlers=[(r"/", MainHandler)])
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Output:

```
$ python test.py 
[I 130529 03:18:35 test:21] outer starts
[I 130529 03:18:35 test:29] inner runs
[I 130529 03:18:35 test:29] inner runs
[I 130529 03:18:35 test:24] outer ends
[I 130529 03:18:35 web:1514] 200 GET / (127.0.0.1) 1.48ms
```

From Python 3.3 there is no need to use `gen.Result()`, simple `return` will do. In older versions, there will be `'return' with argument inside generator` error.

Also, check: https://github.com/facebook/tornado/issues/759

**Update:**

As for Tornado 2.x I think there is no simple way to hide callbacks. Documentation states:

> In most cases, functions decorated with engine should take a callback
>   argument and invoke it with their result when they are finished. One
>   notable exception is the RequestHandler get/post/etc methods, which
>   use self.finish() in place of a callback argument.

So I'm afraid that those are rather unavoidable. Example:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @tornado.gen.engine
    def get(self):
        res = yield tornado.gen.Task(self.outer)
        self.write(res)
        self.finish()

    def inner(self, callback):
        logging.info('inner runs')
        callback()

    @tornado.gen.engine
    def outer(self, callback):
        logging.info('outer starts')
        yield tornado.gen.Task(self.inner)
        yield tornado.gen.Task(self.inner)
        logging.info('outer ends')
        callback("hello")
```

Comment: weeeell, yes, thanks for your answer, but unfortunately I forgot to mention, that I am restricted to tornado 2.x. Otherwise, I am glad to know, one has to jump through less hoops in tornado 3. Thanks for your effort nonetheless

Comment: right, thanks a lot. That, basically, confirms, that the approach, that I've presented in my question is the only one, which is good to know.